# How to hide any menu for special groups on odoo-8?

Tags: security, odoo, odoo-8, usergroups

I'm trying to hide a top menu for a new custom group which I created :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>    
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_sales_users">            
            <field name="name">Sales Users</field>                              
        </record>
        <record id="sales_simple_user" model="res.groups">          
            <field name="name">Simple User</field>                      
            <field name="category_id" ref="module_sales_users"/>        
        </record>       
        <record id="mail.mail_feeds_main" model="ir.ui.menu" >          
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(3,ref('sales_simple_user'))]"/>     
        </record>       
    </data>
</openerp>
```

But when I assign a user to this group, the menu is always shown !

Please what's the mistake in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due that this user belongs to another group (like Human Resources) with permission access to this menu

Comment: Thanks for answer, please how could I inherit for example employee group to hide some menu like 'Messaging' ?

Comment: Personally i would try overriding menu record like you but with something like [(6,0,ref(groups_i_want_to_give_permission)] tuple

Comment: Please could you show me the code in your answer ? does it do what I want ?